# install dependencies from CRAN for a package installed from source

Tags: r, cran

I want to give a beta version of my package to a coworker for testing purposes.
I build the package and put the `.zip` file on the Network Folder.

**The Problem is, how to tell R that it should install the package from the ZipFile but its dependencies from CRAN?**

```r
install.packages("path\\to\\zipfile.zip", source = TRUE, repos = NULL)
```

Because `repos =  null` disables the dependency resultion. If under stand the documentation correctly:

> dependencies
> logical indicating whether to also install uninstalled packages which these packages depend on/link to/import/suggest (and so on recursively). Not used if repos = NULL. Can also be a character vector, a subset of c("Depends", "Imports", "LinkingTo", "Suggests", "Enhances").

I would like to give the coworker a short snippet of code to install for himself without him having to interact further with the installation.

Comment: `install.packages(<character vector with your dependencies>)`?

Answer (score 0):

As the Imports or dependencies might change in later development, i would prefer not to hardcode them.

I found `devtools::install()` which satisfies this requirement. Although it needs devtools.